# Computing the integral using Green's theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

I have been doing an exercise problem in Multivariable calculus, namely I used Green's theorem. But there is something in the solution that I do not fully understand.

1)(Marked by the red rectangle): How did they get that  $f_x(x,y)$  is equal to the specified, they didn't use any chain rule in order to calculate the derivative of  $f(x,y)$?

2)Also, after that they wrote: "On $C$ we have $f_x(x,y)=g'(2)x/2=x/2$". Didn't they calculate $f_{xx}$ here, and not $f_x$?

[image]

Comment: I can see the Chain Rule. It is the radical term in the denominator followed by the linear term in the numerator

Comment: And where is $g$?

Comment: I am not following you here. The derivative of $g(x,y)$ is taken with respect to $x$ as $g'(x,y)$times$(x,y)'$ , latter part with respect to $x$. The only thing that "worries" me is that $2$ in the denominator that I was expecting to go away after the derivative of $x^2$ in the numerator, which would be $2x$. Which textbook is this?

Comment: I understand, thanks. And the 2) part of my question?
It is an exercise problem from the course material of the course that I am taking.

Comment: Given $x^2+y^2=4$ so $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=2$. Plug in first derivative and it will work